# How do I summon an item that has an owner and a pickup delay of -1?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make an item that has no pickup delay, and also a different item that has an owner. The commands I have tried are:

```
/summon item ~ ~-1 ~ {Item:{id:"minecraft:stone",Count:1b},PickupDelay:-1}
```

and

```
/summon item ~ ~-1 ~ {Item:{id:"minecraft:stone",Count:1b},Owner:playerx}
```

Is there a different format for the nbt tags for owner and pickup delay?

Comment: Well, what about these commands is not working? The commands *seem* fine at first glance, so if you could provide details of what is not working, we should be able to pinpoint your issue faster.

Answer (score 1):

`Owner` is not a `TAG_String`, it is a `TAG_Int_Array` that represents the entity’s [UUID](https://minecraft.wiki/w/UUID). Therefore, you can’t just type a player name. You’ll have to get the UUID values from the player you want and copy them to the item entity.

Use a command chain to run the following:

1. Summon an item. The 0s are placeholders for where we will use commands to fill in the real UUID.

   ```
   /summon minecraft:item ~ ~ ~ {Item:{id:"minecraft:stone",Count:1b},Owner:[I;0,0,0,0],Tags:["itemToModify"]}
   ```
2. Replace the first UUID value with the one from the player.

   ```
   /data modify entity @e[tag=itemToModify,limit=1] Owner[0] set from entity playerx UUID[0]
   ```
3. Replace the second UUID value with the one from the player.

   ```
   /data modify entity @e[tag=itemToModify,limit=1] Owner[1] set from entity playerx UUID[1]
   ```
4. Replace the third UUID value with the one from the player.

   ```
   /data modify entity @e[tag=itemToModify,limit=1] Owner[2] set from entity playerx UUID[2]
   ```
5. Replace the fourth UUID value with the one from the player.

   ```
   /data modify entity @e[tag=itemToModify,limit=1] Owner[3] set from entity playerx UUID[3]
   ```
6. Remove the tag.

   ```
   /tag @e[tag=itemToModify,limit=1] remove itemToModify
   ```

*I haven’t tested this yet. If you spot something wrong about this solution or it doesn’t work, let me know in the comments below.*